# Django Syntax error

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I am following a Django tutorial, and I have run into a problem with one of my views. When looking at the error output from django it tells me that there is a error on line 62:

```
yr = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1)     months = 12
```

Here is the entire view:

```
def year(request):
    #http://site_name/year/
    post_error = ""
    year = int(year)
    yr = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1)     months = 12
    by_month = []
    if Post.objects.filter(published__year=year).count():
    if year == datetime.datetime.now().year:
        months = datetime.datetime.now().month
    for month in range(1, months+1):
        by_month.append({datetime.datetime(year, month, 1):

    Post.objects.filter(published__month=month).filter(published__year=year)})
    elif year > datetime.datetime.now().year:
    post_error = "It is not yet %d, try an earlier year." % year
    else:
    post_error = "There are not posts for %d." % year
    return render_to_response('year.html', {'by_month':by_month, 'post_error':post_error,},)
```

Please tell me if you need anymore information that I have not provided. Thanks! -Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two statements on one line; that's a syntax error. Put them on two separate lines:

```
yr = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1)
months = 12
```

Technically, you could also join multiple statements with a `;` semi-colon, but that is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

You missing a newline between function call and var declaration:

```
year = int(year)
yr = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1)
months = 12
by_month = []
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   yr = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1)     months = 12
```

One error: Indention fault in the above line! Move the "months=12" declaration to next line

Comment: the previous as correct answers - the statement months = 12 should be in its own line.